# How to create a nested list of RDS files in R?

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I am trying to organize a bunch of RDS files from a folder in to a list in R. Each RDS file is a predictive model that has been trained at an earlier time. The list is supposed to be structured by bag_number, title, and c. There are 5 bags, 2 titles, and 10 C's for a total of 100 elements in the list. The idea is to be able to pull a specific model out of the list with model[[bag_number]][[t]][[c]].  I have tried using lapply to create my nested list with the following code, but it's giving me Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection .

```
models<-lapply(1:5,function(bag_number){
  lapply(1:2,function(t){
    lapply(1:10,function(c){
      readRDS(paste("./saved models/trained_models_",titles[t],"_",bag_number,"_dna",c,".rds",sep=""))
    })
  })
})
```

if I just run the inner most lapply it works, but it just gives me one piece of the list. What is the correct way to construct a nested list?

Comment: Have you tried printing the filename inside the inner loop? Somewhere you’re constructing an incorrect/nonexistent filename. Besides that, the code works fine.

Comment: That was it! Print is a really smart way to see what is happening in code. Thanks.